# MySQL Error 1062: Duplicate entry for key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, unique

I have made a SQL script that creates and fill some tables that I will use with Django framework.

In my **date** table I create the *mois* column with the UNIQUE constraint as described:

```
    CREATE TABLE date (
        dateID int NOT NULL,
        annee int NOT NULL,
        mois int NOT NULL,
        .
        .
        CONSTRAINT PK_date PRIMARY KEY (dateID, annee, mois, semaine, jour),
        UNIQUE KEY idx_mois (mois),
    ) Engine=innoDB;
```

Here is the FKs definition:

```
CREATE TABLE astreinte_mensu (
dateID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
annee int,
mois int,
Personne1Nuit int,
Personne2Nuit int,
Personne1Jour int,
Personne2Jour int,
FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES date(annee),
FOREIGN KEY (mois) REFERENCES date(mois),
FOREIGN KEY (Personne1Nuit) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
FOREIGN KEY (Personne2Nuit) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
FOREIGN KEY (Personne1Jour) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
FOREIGN KEY (Personne2Jour) REFERENCES contact(PersonID)
```

) Engine=innoDB;

Later in the script i have my procedure **fill_date**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date()
BEGIN
DECLARE currentdate DATE;
DECLARE stopdate DATE;
SET currentdate = CURDATE();
SET stopdate = ADDDATE(currentdate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
INSERT INTO date VALUES (
YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
YEAR(currentdate),
MONTH(currentdate),
WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
DAY(currentdate));

SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
END WHILE;
END
```

When I launch the file I got an error related to duplicate entry.

So my table goes from June 2018 to June 2019 and that is causing the error..

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 121: Duplicate entry '6' for key 'idx_mois'

Can someone light my candle ?

**EDIT:**
The UNIQUE constraint is needed for the argument *ForeignKey.to_field* in Django, because I would like to link the *Astreinte_mensu.Mois* field to the *Date.mois* field.
This way I hope it displays the months instead of the complete date as shown in this [Screenshot of django Admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIwmj.png)

Comment: You probably don't want an unique constraint on `mois`, since it means you can only ever have a single row of data on a specific `mois`, even on different `annee`, `semaine` or `jour`. What did you want to do with that unique constraint? (for other readers : `mois` = month, `annee` = year, `semaine` = week, `jour` = day)

Comment: the UNIQUE constraint is needed for the *ForeignKey argument* **ForeignKey.to_field** ..

Comment: Can you add the FK definition to your question ? It should probably be the FK target table having an unique constraint (e.g. if it's describing the months names, you don't want to have one row saying month 1 is january and another saying month 1 is february)

Comment: @Aaron done! :)

Comment: You really don't want to be using math to combine parts of a date into a date. Use the [date formatting functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) if you *must* wrangle something into a `YYYYMMDD` format, but `YYYY-MM-DD` is the default format for a `DATE` type field.

Comment: Yeah i'll definitly try to do that in a different way. Thank you

Comment: Yeah I don't think the two FK on annee and mois will do you any good. Not sure what to propose instead though, sorry

Comment: As a rule of thumb: a foreign key always refers to a primary key. If it doesn't, you probably did something wrong in your database model. (There are exception to this rule, but don't start with them). E.g. your primary key in the date table is clearly just `dateid` (you can calculate the other 4 values directly from `dateid`, which also means that `annee`/`moins` aren't allowed in `astreinte_mensu`). It seems you want to solve a different problem by breaking the model and then fixing the problems that result from this, instead of looking for a better way to implement your admin form field.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have columns for the components of a date; instead split on the `SELECT` side using the various [*datetime functions*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Use date arithmetic functions in preference over numeric and string functions.  Example `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH`.

`UNIQUE KEY idx_mois (mois)` implies that you will not have more than 12 rows in that table?  Or do you somehow have more than 12 months?  Perhaps you did not mean `UNIQUE`?

Comment: Somehow I was trying to have dates over several years so several times 12 months and both the UNIQUE constraint to be able to assign the date.month field specifically to the on-call.month field in order to have the right thing displayed in my Django Admin Form.